# How to render and display the index.html file generated by DITA-OT plugin from AEM in React project?

Tags: html, reactjs, dita-ot

We have a `index.html` file which is generated by `DITA-OT` plugin from `AEM tool`. We would like to display the `index.html` file content within the react app.

Do we have any standard method to render/ display a HMTL file within react app?